# Can I define a javascript variable to a grails object?

Tags: javascript, html, grails

Can I assign a javascript variable to a grails object like this?

```
var newReport = ${report};
```

`report` is a grails domain object, which is passed back from controller to the gsp file.

Currently this doesn't work in my page.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that report is a Grails domain class, you will have to 'translate' this to a valid javascript format. One way is to set this as JSON. Something like:

**In the controller**

```
def reportJson = report as JSON
```

**In the gsp**

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
  var newReport = $.parseJSON("${reportJson}");
</script>
```

The parseJSON takes the json string and return a javascript object.

Comment: Could also do `$.parseJSON("${report as JSON}");` if you didn't want to update the controller.

Answer (score 0):

Just render domain object as JSON to gsp, where some javascript code get the json by **eval()** function. For instance:

domain class - Band:

```
String bandName    //some property
...
```

controller:

```
def bands = Band.list()
render(template:"result", model:[bands:bands as JSON]
```

_result.gsp:

```
<script>
    var bandList = eval(${bands});
    for(i=0; i<bandList.length; i++){   
        var name = bandList[i].bandName;
        ....
    }
    ....
</script>
```